# Heroku | Different performance parameters for different parts of your application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rack

I have an Rails 3 application hosted on heroku, it has pretty common configuration where I have a client facing part of my application say: www.myapplication.com and an admin part of my application admin.myapplication.com.

I want my client facing part of my application to be fast, and I don't really care about how fast my admin module is.  What I do care about is that I do not want usage on my admin site to slow down the client facing part of my application.

Ideally my client-side of the app with have 3 dedicated dynos, and my admin side will have 1 dedicated dyno.

Does anyone have any idea on the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you split the applications you're going to have share the database connections between the two apps. To be honest, I'd just have it one single app and give it 4 dynos :)

Also, Dynos don't increase performance, they increase throughput so you're capable of dealing with more requests a second.

For example,

Roughly - If a typical page response is 100ms, 1 dyno could process 10 requests a second. If you only have a single dyno and your app suddenly receives 10 requests per second then the excess requests will be queued until the dyno is free'd up to process those requests. Also requests > 30s will be timed out.

If you add a second dyno requests would be shared between the 2 dynos so you'd now be able to process 20 requests a second (in an ideal world) and so on as you add more dynos.

And remember a dyno is single threaded, so if it's doing something *ANYTHING* ie rendering a page, building a pdf and including receiving an uploaded image etc then it's busy and unable to process further requests until it's finished and if you don't have an more dynos requests will be queued.

Comment: A dyno is not single threaded. The Rails application might be (check https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn). A dyno has access to 4 cores.

Comment: To be fair, this comment is from the Bamboo days where Thin was the only option.  These days with Cedar you can run all sorts of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to split your application into it's logical parts. Having a separate application for the admin interface is a good thing.

It does not have to be on the same domain as the main application. It could have a global client IP restriction or just a simple global Basic Auth.

Why complicate things and stuff two things into one application? This also lets you eperimenting more with the admin part and redeploy it without affecting your users.